# How to addd a custom property spring data elastic search request

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Elastic search team added a property `"ignore_unmapped": true`, used to avoid an error when the index is empty and elastic tries anyway to sort the empty result.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": "15",
    "sort": {
        "title": {
            "order": "asc",
            "ignore_unmapped": true
        }
    }
}
```

How could I add this `"ignore_unmapped": true` in a spring data elastic search request ? I don't find any example in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported. I created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1911) to address this.